# How to get value from one column of a text file for values of another column

Tags: python

I am reading data from a text file. The text file basically contains values like this

```
1 2 5
1 3 5
1 5 8
2 2 10
2 3 5
2 5 4
```

My code

```
data = np.loadtxt('test.txt')
player = data.T[0]
position = data.T[1]
score = data.T[2]
```

Basically if i want to find all the scores of player 1 i will do `score[player==1]` it will give me 5,5,10. But i want to find all the score values that are common for two players so if i do this `score[player==1 or player==2]` I get an error saying :

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is
>   ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Please advice how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gives you all scores for players 1 and 2 combined:

```
>>> score[np.logical_or(player==1, player==2)]
array([  5.,   5.,   8.,  10.,   5.,   4.])
```

If you are looking for the intersection of the scores between both players use:

```
>>> np.intersect1d(score[player==1], score[player==2])
5.0
```

Comment: can you please explain what logical_or is ?

Comment: also it seems when i do your approach it will give me an array[truth,false,truth...] something like that so i am wondering is it possible to get actual values instead?

Comment: `logical_or` is essentially an `or` working on arrays.